# how to mange tab laoding in tab bar in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, tabbar

[tabbar Activity here](https://github.com/kuldeep2900/FragmentTabBar)i attach view pager code in below, my problem  in tab bar ,when i launch this activity tab1 and tab 2 load automatic. i want only tab 1 when i scroll tab 1 to tab tab 2 ,then tab 3 loaded not tab 2 (but i want when we scroll tab1 to tab 2 then only tab 2 load )and when i  scroll   tab 4 to tab 5 then nothing is loaded(i want when i scroll tab 4 to tab 5 then tab 5 load)same happening when i scroll tab 2 to Tab 1 nothing is loaded but (i want tab tab 1 loaded).and when i scroll Tab 3 to tab 2 then tab 1 is loaded (but i want  tab 2 loaded)i am facing this problem before one month to till now.
    package activity;

Comment: check visibility of that fragment.

Comment: Please provide your pager adapter code

Comment: https://github.com/kuldeep2900/FragmentTabBar please check this github link i am adding pager adapter code here

Answer (score 1):

In your 'getItem()' method ,I think you have reversed tab2<->tab3 try interchanging it